# How to setup remote Perforce server so it can be accessed from the web

Tags: perforce

I have my Windows 10 Perforce service running with the following config:

`p4 -p 192.168.0.24:1666 info`

> User name: Austinlele
> Client name: LAPTOP-ABCD
> Client host: LAPTOP-ABCD
> Client unknown.
> Current directory: C:/Users/me
> Peer address: 192.168.0.24:64301
> Client address: 192.168.0.24
> Server address: LAPTOP-ABCD.Home:1666
> Server root: C:\Program Files\Perforce\Server
> Server date: 2021/03/09 13:05:38 -0600 Central Standard Time
> Server uptime: 00:01:36
> Server version: P4D/NTX64/2020.1/2089982 (2021/02/28)
> Server license: none
> Case Handling: insensitive

I've tried to follow the steps here: https://community.perforce.com/s/article/13219 but they are unclear.. I have tried to run `p4 set -S Perforce P4PORT=1666` to change the server address, and then do a `svcinst stop -n "Perforce"` and  `svcinst start -n "Perforce"` to restart the service, but nothing changes.

They mention getting your public IP address, but do not say what to do with it.

Basically I want to host a private Perforce server and allow a friend to collaborate with me from outside my home network. Perforce documentation seems abysmally lacking in my opinion.. So thank you for any and all help!

Comment: Which specific steps from the KB article are unclear?  The main thing is that your public IP needs to route to the machine your server is running on.  You don't give any details about what sort of router/firewall you're using, and you don't say whether your friend is even attempting to connect to your public IP.

Comment: I went to whatismyip.com to find the external IP of the server, so that should route correctly. I have a pretty standard centurylink modem/router combo. I opened the port 1666 for my server's local IP, but cant for the public one. I set the firewall to not block 1666 overall. Friend is trying the public IP.

Comment: Did you set up port forwarding on the router?  https://www.centurylink.com/home/help/internet/modems-and-routers/advanced-setup/port-forwarding.html  Note that if your Perforce server is listening on port 1666, that's the port you want to forward (the KB article makes the assumption that you want the server to run on port 80, which is required by some firewall setups, but I don't think it's necessarily needed here.)

Comment: I have forwarded 1666 on my router, which is what I am setting as the Perforce port. I think you're right that I shouldnt have to use 80.

Comment: What error does your friend see when they try to connection to `your.public.ip:1666`?